# ARToolKit: processing of Natural Feature Tracking images (jpegs) on the mobile device itself

Tags: java, android, c++, vuforia, artoolkit

I've been using Vuforia for a while now which has the limitation that I can't directly submit to the Natural Feature Tracking processor an image for turning into a trackable data file. Instead it is hard wired to take the image directly from the camera, which gives me no control. See for example the `UserDefinedTargets` demo.

Does ARToolKit allow me to submit a jpeg to the NFT processor **directly from my mobile device** for processing ? I want to be able to achieve something like `UserDefinedTargets` on Vuforia, but with the ability to submit my own natural feature images as jpegs on the mobile device itself. I can then save images taken on the fly for future processing, or even better, save the processed NFT data for future use. I do not want to use some cloud service, e.g. there is a workaround with Vuforia, but I have to use their cloud service and that has its limitations too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation here: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_nft_training you have a program that can be used to do the feature extraction. It works with a digital image so without having looked into the code I foresee two options for you:

a) Check out the source code and see if you can get that tool running inside an Android phone, most likely via NDK

b) Make a web service that receives an image, runs this program and returns the result, so you can use it as a normal REST API.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a whirl.